# Convert multiple python strings to object

Tags: python, json, dictionary, object

I have been looking for a solution to my problem for a few hours.
Do you know a method or an algorithm to achieve the following?

```py
#Input

text1 = "network.routes.vlan[0].address"
val1 = "value1"
text2 = "network.routes.vlan[1].address"
val2 = "value2"
text3 = "network.routes.vlan[2].address"
val3 = "value3"
text3 = "network.interface.name"
val3 = "name_interface"

merge_variables_to_unique_object()

#Output

[{
    network: {
        routes : {
            vlan: [
                {
                    address: value1
                },
                {
                    address: value2
                },
                {
                    address: value3
                }
            ]
        },
        interface: {
            name: name_interface
        }
    }
}]
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: No it's not, I'm not a student anymore.

Comment: I've already tried for several hours, hence my post here.
```text = "network.routes.vlan[0].address"
obj = {}

txt_arr = text.split(".")

for index, i in enumerate(txt_arr):
    if index == 0:
        if ((txt_arr[index] in obj) == False):
            obj[txt_arr[index]] = []
    else:
        if (len(txt_arr)) == 2:
            obj[txt_arr[0]] = txt_arr[1]
        if (len(txt_arr)) == 3:
            obj[txt_arr[0]] = {txt_arr[1]: { txt_arr[2] : {} }}
        if (len(txt_arr)) == 4:
            obj[txt_arr[0]] = {txt_arr[1] : [{txt_arr[2] : [{txt_arr[3]}]}]}```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I would make an array of all of the values

```
values = [[text1, val1], [text2, val2], [text3, val3], [name, name_interface]]
# name and name_interface are the last two values
```

Then, I would make the function take a list of values and create a base dictionary for adding values into.

```
def merge_variables_to_unique_object(values: list):
    base_json = {
        "network": {
            "routes": {
                "vlan": [
                    
                ]
            },
            "interface": {
                
            }
        }
    }
```

After that, it's just a simple for loop that goes until the length of the `values` array. Inside of the array, you check if you are at the last element of the array. If you are not at the end, you add the values to the array (remember that `vlan` is a dictionary)

```
base_json["network"]["routes"]["vlan"].append({values[i][0]: values[i][1]})
```

If you are at the last element of the array, you add the values to interface:

```
base_json["network"]["interface"][values[i][0]] = values[i][1]
```

The for loop would look like this:

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    if i < len(values) - 1:
        base_json["network"]["routes"]["vlan"].append({values[i][0]: values[i][1]})
    else:
        base_json["network"]["interface"][values[i][0]] = values[i][1]
```

Afterwards, you would just return `base_json` because it was changed inside of the for loop.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good start! But I would like it to be dynamic, i.e. if I want to add a new 
```text4 = network.test.container.content
val4 = "value4"```
for example, it will automatically add itself to my object and create new attributes test, container, and content to the already created network
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the content in this syntactical format you can simply write it to an file or an string. Either way it will be something like this.  This is manually creating the syntax you want that you can write to an file to force through .json.

`input1 = text1.split(".")`
`input2 = text2.split(".")`
and so on

`str1="[{\n\tinput1[1]:  {\n\t\tinput1[2] : {\n\t\t\tinput1[3]"`
in this fashion

`\t` are tabs like indenting in code
`\n` is interpreted in strings as next line.

Is this helpful?

Comment: Thank you, this is a good start! But I would like it to be dynamic, i.e. if I want to add a new 
```text4 = network.test.container.content
val4 = "value4"```
for example, it will automatically add itself to my object and create new attributes test, container, and content to the already created network
Thank you very much in advance!